# Switching between two divs that contain the same local variable and updating the local variable after editing it

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I have a container with two divs like so:

```
<div>
  <div>
     <%= best_in_place @obj, :comment, :type => :textarea, :display_as => :display %>
     <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>'.html_safe, '#', onclick: "$(this).closest('.preview').hide().siblings().show();"  %>
  </div>
  <div>
     <%= best_in_place @obj, :comment, :type => :textarea %>
     <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>'.html_safe, '#', onclick: "$(this).closest('.full-body').hide().prev().show();" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the click of a button I can switch between the two divs. Everything works fine until I change the state of one div by editing the textarea using the best_in_place helper. For example, in the first div I'm editing a textarea. When it's displaying the best_in_place in the first div (the one with :display_as) and I edit that textarea and then switch to the second div, the second div displays the old textarea. How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably need to know more about how you're switching between the divs before anyone can give you a concrete answer. Pure javascript to toggle between display:none and display:block? or some other method?

Comment: As shown in the code above in the link_to helper, I'm using jquery.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about ruby, so I don't know what link_to does, but if you're just hide()ing and show()ing as you are in the example, it shouldn't reset your html. Can you make a fiddle showing the behavior? The only thing I could think of that's resetting the HTML would be if the page was reloading due to the click